# Domain of $f(x) = \dfrac{(3x + \left|x\right|)}x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For the equation $$f(x) = \dfrac{(3x + |x|)}x$$ how do you algebraically figure out the domain of the function?

I know it's continuous all the way, but I've tried to split the function into $3x+|x|$ which is continuous in all instances of x and then 1/x which is not continuous at zero.

How come this function's domain is still continuous even though 1/x cannot exist at zero?

*I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.*

Comment: Does the function have a limit as $x\to 0$?  How do you know the domain is continuous?

Comment: What do you mean by "the domain is continous"? How can a **set** be continous or not?

Comment: When you see an absolute value, split it up: for positive values, and negative ones. It's quite helpful.

Comment: @user127001 The concept isn't meaningless, even though there's no property that's called "continuos" for sets, I think either "open", "connected", or "simply connected" may express what he means

Comment: @Shuri what properties do you know about operations on functions, and what happens to their domain?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, let me clarify: I meant that when I graphed the function, it seemed continuous (D:{xeR})

Comment: @GPerez I know since there is an absolute value in the numerator, I can express the function like a peicewise one, but I think I am a bit cloudy on what to do after that; isn't ans absolute value function continuous?

Comment: @Shuri the piecewise expression doesn't matter, as long as you know that the domain of $|x|$ is all of $\mathbb R$. What I meant is, if you have two functions $f,g$ with domains $\ U,V$ what happens with $U,V$ for the function $f+g$? what about $fg$, or $f/g$? Are the new domains independent of the original ones? Probably not... well then... do we intersect? Union? As it turns out there is a set of rules and they're universal, so learning them is probably a good idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering the question, I'd like to dispel what seems to be a misconception. This question about domain has nothing to do with continuity.

You may be confused because in many practical cases, a function is continuous at all points in its domain. For example, this is the case for rational functions. But there are other cases where this is not true.

A function $f$ is *defined* at a point $a$ when it makes sense to calculate $f(a)$. This is the same as saying that $a$ is in the domain of $f$.

A function $f$ is *continuous* at a point $a$ if, not only is $f$ defined at $a$, but $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists *and* equals $f(a)$.

To solve your problem, you need to answer the following question: for what values of $x$ does the expression $\frac{3x + |x|}{x}$ make sense?

$3x$ always makes sense, and so does $|x|$. Also, you can always add two numbers, no matter what they are. So $3x + |x|$ always makes sense.

The main point, however, is that you can't always divide a number $A$ by a number $B$. When does a fraction $A/B$ make sense?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Simplify the function for positive and negative values of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x>0\longrightarrow f(x)=\frac{3x+|x|}{x}=\frac{3x+\color{red}{x}}{x}=\frac{4x}{x}=4$$  and $$x<0\longrightarrow f(x)=\frac{3x+|x|}{x}=\frac{3x+(\color{blue}{-x})}{x}=\frac{2x}{x}=2$$ and if $x=0$ then ...

[image]

Comment: @J.W.Perry: Oh yes. I did a bad simplification. Fixed and Thanks.

Comment: This was a clear answer as well, thank you!

Comment: No problemo there. Good concise answer.